# Angular ng-repeat clear all the value in view

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
<body ng-controller="StockController as stockCtrl">
    <div ng-repeat="obj in stockCtrl.stocks" class="stock">
      <h1 class="text-center">{{obj.resource.fields.symbol}}</h1>
      <h1 class="text-center">{{obj.resource.fields.price | currency }}</h1>
      <div class="row">
        <input type="text" class="form-control target-price" ng-model="stock.high">
        <button class="btn btn-primary">Watch</button>
        <input type="text" class="form-control target-price" ng-model="stock.low">
        {{stock}}
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
```

**Controller**

```
function StockController($http, $interval){
  var stockCtrl = this;
  stockCtrl.stocks = [];

  $interval(function(){
    $http.jsonp('http://finance.yahoo.com/webservice/v1/symbols/APPL/quote?format=json&callback=JSON_CALLBACK')
    .success(function(data){
        stockCtrl.stocks = data.list.resources;
      });
  },2000);

}
```

Here every second Ajax pulls data from REST and puts the result into an array. I am looping through that array with ng-repeat to show those values on the view. i have two other ng-model values in that ng-repeat. When ever ng-repeat re rendering the view, it clearing the other ng-model values as well(in this case 'high' and 'low'). Why this is happening. How to prevent this?

Here is the sceneria: Ajax pulls multiple stocks. I will set different high and low values for each stock, beacause i want to sell when that particular stock reaches its high or low. So i want those high and low to stay there for each stock. only the stock price would change
Ultimate i am going to write a watcher for that stock object to current stock price with its high and low

Comment: what is `high` and `low`? Shouldn't it be something like `obj.high` and `obj.low`? You are absolutely breaking cardinal rule of always having an object in `ng-model`. Primitives don't have inheritance and `ng-repeat` creates child scopes

Comment: updated. But same problem

Comment: @LokeshCherukuri: you have something like this right....     this.stock = {};
    this.stock.high = "somevalue";
    this.stock.low = "somevalue";

Comment: Need to explain what you expect those models to do. Broken code isn't  good substitute for  proper explanation

Comment: I want to write a watcher on that stock model

Answer (score 0):

Its a guess here, your `high and low` are not objects and pure local  `variables` so its getting lost on `ng-repeat` as it creates a new scope and also re-renders the view.

```
<body ng-controller="StockController as stockCtrl">
    <div ng-repeat="obj in stockCtrl.stocks" class="stock">
      <h1 class="text-center">{{obj.resource.fields.symbol}}</h1>
      <h1 class="text-center">{{obj.resource.fields.price | currency }}</h1>
      <div class="row">
        <input type="text" class="form-control target-price" ng-model="high">
        <button class="btn btn-primary">Watch</button>
        <input type="text" class="form-control target-price" ng-model="low">
        {{high}}
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
```

You could fix this by change `this.high and this.low` to like this below:

```
this.someObject = {};
this.someObject.high = "somevalue";
this.someObject.low = "somevalue";
```

Comment: But i need high & low values for each stock. If i have 10 stocks in ng-repeat, i need 10 high and low values

Comment: You need to store those values in $localStorage, and check if something is already there then re-populate or else use the stock.ng-model which would be the ng-repeat value for high and low.

Comment: I am not going to refresh the page. So do i need local storage.

Comment: Mixing $scope syntax in view with controllerAs `this` in controller

Comment: @LokeshCherukuri: You are re-rendering the same view with the stocks array, so your ng-model input bound to stock.high and stock.low is lost and new value gets updated...

Comment: Is there any solution?

Comment: why don't you store the entire stocks array in $localStorage and when re-rendering... update the high and low from the last updated $localStorage value... but may @charlietfl could have a better solution here.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a couple of things are happening: first, you're clearing the high and low models each time you render the page since they don't have placeholders inside of the controller. For that I would switch from two way binding and do one way binding so as to hold the values or at least create placeholders in the controller. Second, you're binding high and low to every repeated stock instance. Which, if it hasn't already, is going to cause you problems in the future.

Comment: I want high&low to persist even the stock change. I will enter  those values into text boxes.

Comment: Then you should switch to an object that holds each individual row's stock prices in parallel to the stock object array. The problem with that is you're assuming the REST call will always return the same entities in the same order so you'll also have to coordinate based off of a unique value which doesn't change for each stock

Answer (score 0):

ng-repeat will load all the data inside it whenever a new AJAX request is made which updates the main Array in ng-repeat

You may have to do the following:

1) Link the ng-model values to the ng-repeat array itself as

```
ng-model="obj.low"
ng-model="obj.high"
```

2) Then on each change (you can use ng-change() etc. ) to store the array locally in case you are not submitting it to backend. Use $sessionStorage.obj (say)

3) At each updation using AJAX call, you need to check if $sessionStorage has value of high and low as:

```
$interval(function(){
    $http.jsonp('http://finance.yahoo.com/webservice/v1/symbols/APPL/quote?format=json&callback=JSON_CALLBACK')
    .success(function(data){
        var response = data.list.resources;
        angular.forEach(response, function(item){

             angular.forEach($sessionStorage.obj, function(obj){

                if(item.low != obj.low){
                    item.low = obj.low
                }
                if(item.high != obj.high){
                    item.high = obj.high
                }
             });

        });

        stockCtrl.stocks = response;

      });
  },2000);
```

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to keep a separate object using each ticker as keys

```
$scope.myData={
    'MSFT': {high:54.25, low: 51.67},
    'AAPL': {high:99.26, low: 97.89}

}
```

Then in view:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control target-price" ng-model="myData[obj.symbol].high">
```

You could then also store this in localStorage for persistence between page loads